# Add 10 Minutes to 7:30am PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I'm too frustrated to find it.  All I want to do is add X amount of minutes to X o'clock.

So, in my case for example I have a time 7:30am that I want to add 2:20 (two minutes and 20 seconds) to.  (specifically in those formats).

I've even done this before, but it seems like every time I try to hash out a new PHP time function it's like I've entered the land of formatting errors.   Thanks for your input and I'm bookmarking this answer for the rest of my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding 2 minutes and 20 seconds to 7:30AM:

```
$dt = new DateTime('7:30 AM');
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT2M20S'));
echo $dt->format('H:i:s')."\n";
```

Output:

```
07:32:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a timestamp, add 600 seconds and convert it back.